# How do I get what's inbetween " " in a user inputted String? Java

Tags: java, string, substring, double-quotes

I'd like to retrieve whatever is in quotes that someone enters as a string, i'm assuming it's substring that I need but i'm not sure how.

When the user inputs a string mixed with words and numbers all separated by one space:
 hey 110 say "I am not very good at Java" but " I can fish pretty well"

Then I want to be able to take the "I am not very good at Java" and the "I can fish pretty well" and print out what's inside the quotes so there can be multiple quotes in the string.
right now I have if( userInput=='"') then I do something with substring but i'm not sure what.

I can't use split, trim, tokenizer, regex or anything that would make this really easy unfortunatley.

it's all in this method where I try to identify if something in the string is a word, number or a quote:

```
public void set(String userInput)// method set returns void
    {
        num=0;// reset each variable so new input can be passed

        String empty="";
        String wordBuilder="";
        userInput+=" ";
        for(int index=0; index<userInput.length(); index++)// goes through each character in string
        {

            if(Character.isDigit(userInput.charAt(index)))// checks if character in the string is a digit
            { 

                empty+=userInput.charAt(index);



            }
            else
            { 
                if (Character.isLetter(userInput.charAt(index)))
            {

                wordBuilder+=userInput.charAt(index);

            }
                else
                {
                    if(userInput.charAt(index)=='"')
                {
                    String quote=(userInput.substring(index,);

                }
                }
                //if it is then parse that character into an integer and assign it to num
                num=Integer.parseInt(empty);
                word=wordBuilder;


                empty="";
                wordBuilder="";
            }


        } 

    }


}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use `String#indexOf`, `String#lastIndexOf` and `String#subString`...?

Comment: yes but indexOf only takes the first value in the string and lastIndexOf only takes the last I want it to work if there are several quotes

Comment: I didn't get a good answer on that one.

Comment: Then why did you accept one?

Comment: I thought i'd be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this quite what you are looking for, but it will strip down the quoted parts in steps...

```
String quote = "I say: \"I have something to say, \"It's better to burn out then fade away\"\" outloud...";

if (quote.contains("\"")) {

    while (quote.contains("\"")) {
        int startIndex = quote.indexOf("\"");
        int endIndex = quote.lastIndexOf("\"");
        quote = quote.substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex);
        System.out.println(quote);
    }

}
```

Which outputs...

```
I have something to say, "It's better to burn out then fade away"
It's better to burn out then fade away
```

**Updated**

I don't know if this is cheating or not...

```
String quote = "I say: \"I have something to say, \"It's better to burn out then fade away\"\" outloud...\"Just in case you don't believe me\"";

String[] split = quote.split("\"");
for (String value : split) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Which outputs...

```
I say: 
I have something to say, 
It's better to burn out then fade away

 outloud...
Just in case you don't believe me
```

**Updated**

Okay, fake `String#split`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(quote.length());
for (int index = 0; index < quote.length(); index++) {
    if (quote.charAt(index) == '"') {
        System.out.println(sb);
        sb.delete(0, sb.length());
    } else {
        sb.append(quote.charAt(index));
    }
}
```

**Updated**

Okay, this is basically fake `split` with options...

```
String quote = "blah blah 123 \"hello\" 234 \"world\"";

boolean quoteOpen = false;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(quote.length());
for (int index = 0; index < quote.length(); index++) {
    if (quote.charAt(index) == '"') {
        if (quoteOpen) {
            System.out.println("Quote: [" + sb.toString() + "]");
            quoteOpen = false;
            sb.delete(0, sb.length());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Text: [" + sb.toString() + "]");
            sb.delete(0, sb.length());
            quoteOpen = true;
        }
    } else {
        sb.append(quote.charAt(index));
    }
}
if (sb.length() > 0) {
    if (quoteOpen) {
        System.out.println("Quote: [" + sb.toString() + "]");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Text: [" + sb.toString() + "]");
    }
}
```

Which generates...

```
Text: [blah blah 123 ]
Quote: [hello]
Text: [ 234 ]
Quote: [world]
```

Know, I don't know how you are storing the results.  I would be tempted to create some basic classes which were capable of storing the `String` results and add them to a `List` so I could maintain the order and maybe use a flag of some kind to determine what type they are...

Comment: Thanks this would be awesome! but i'm trying to not always go back to the first time the " was inputted and the last.

Comment: Yea not allowed to use split :(

Comment: Hmm, but I don't know the length of the quote so far it's just a bunch of characters in a string

Comment: Which quote?  Do you care about compound quotes?

Comment: The user will input something like: blah blah 123 "hello" 234 "world" . I want to identify what is a word a number or a quote and print out each one, so i'd identify a quote by if userInput charAt(index)=='"' and i'd want to print out everything from that initial " to it's end " but i don't know the length of each quote only the entire string

Comment: I would say you don't need to (know the length of the quote)

Comment: you just had (quote.length()); in your code I assumed that's what it was. I'm just not really sure how to find where it ends

Comment: Sorry, `quote` is just the incoming `String`....probably should have called it `text` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try the next:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "\"123\" hey 110 say \"I am not very good at Java\" but \" I can fish pretty well\"";
    int indexQuote = -1;
    boolean number = true;
    String data = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char ch = input.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
            if (data.length() > 0 && indexQuote == -1) {
                if (number) {
                    System.out.println("It's a number: " + data);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("It's a word: " + data);
                }
                // reset vars
                number = true;
                data = "";
            } else if (indexQuote != -1) {
                data += ch;
            }
        } else if (ch == '"') {
            if (indexQuote == -1) {
                number = false;
                indexQuote = i;
            } else {
                System.out.println("It's a quote: " + data);
                // reset vars
                number = true;
                data = "";
                indexQuote = -1;
            }
        } else {
            if (!Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                number = false;
            }
            data += ch;
            if (data.length() > 0 && i == input.length() - 1) {
                if (number) {
                    System.out.println("It's a number: " + data);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("It's a word: " + data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
It's a word: hey
It's a number: 110
It's a word: say
It's a quote: I am not very good at Java
It's a word: but
It's a quote:  I can fish pretty well
```

Comment: I can't use this. regex or patterns or anything

Comment: I'm not allowed to use arrays and it can only scan the user input once. sorry this is a great answer though

Comment: Not problem. Without arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the string and use a temporary int variable to store when the quoted string started. When you see that it ends, you can extract that substring and do what you want with it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but how do I see that it ends. it's all in a for loop

Comment: Check if you see a character equal to " while you're currently inside a quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

Use [StringUtils.subStringBetween](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringBetween%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyTestSecond { 
public static void main(String...args){

    String a = "hey 110 say \"I am not very good at Java\"";
    // Method 1
    if(a.contains("\""))
        System.out.println(a.substring(a.indexOf("\""),a.lastIndexOf("\"")+1));
    //Method 2
    String[] array = a.split(" ");
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(array[i].startsWith("\""))
            System.out.println(a.substring(a.indexOf("\""),a.lastIndexOf("\"")+1));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getNextQuote(int index, String sentence){
 return sentence.substring(sentence.indexOf("\"", index + 1), sentence.indexOf("\"", index + 2));
}
```

usage: call the method with an index as parameter. This index resembles the index of the last `"` that you've encountered.

Afterwards, it will return everything between the next two quotes.

Comment: But doesn't indexOf only take the first instance of a " in the string ?

Comment: There's an overload that takes the first occurence, starting from a specified index.

Comment: will it still work when there are several quotes in the string? like :  hello "world" code code "code" 123 "code". and I'm not taking in an index from the user, do I take that in from the setter method that has index in the forloop?

Comment: You should keep the index somewhere in your program when you loop over it to determine what type of character the next char is.